# What does the number indicate in .pfb-files?

Tags: fonts

I'm about to download the [cm small caps](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ps-type1/cm-super) package from CTAN. However there are quite a number of [`sfsc*.pfb` files](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ps-type1/cm-super/pfb) to choose from, where `*` refers to different numbers.

I wonder what these numbers mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number indicate the font's design size.

You can rescale outlines of a font, but if you mix the same design at different sizes (say `10pt` for the text, `12pt` for paragraph titles and and `8pt` for some lesser text) the result is usually odd looking or even illegible.

The best font sets have outlines designed separately at different sizes that can be used together without oddity.

For instance `sfsc1200.pfb` indicates a design size of `12pt` and `sfsc1440.pfb` a design size of `14.40pt`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format

Comment: Thank you for the tip and for reformatting nicely my answer.  It is not that important, but I would definitely not have put sizes between backquotes, since they are not code fragments—or are not intentionally code fragments.